# TextFormField no se redibuja correctamente

Tags: flutter, dart

*Primero mostrare un poco como están esturados los widgets que involucra el problema y luego pasaré a explicar el problema en sí*

### **Estructura de los Widgets**

Tengo el siguiente widget `CaliberTextFormFields` que muestra campos de un formulario con el fin de editar objetos de la clase `Caliber`. Estos objetos `Caliber` se guardan en una lista en la propiedad un objeto de la clase `Product` en el provider `ProductProvider`. El Widget `CaliberTextFormFields` se llama en un `Column`

En resumen sería `Caliber` >> `Product` >> `ProductProvider`

Y los `Caliber` son editados en el `CaliberTextFormFields` que se llama en un `Column`

```
class CaliberTextFormFields extends StatelessWidget {
  const CaliberTextFormFields({
    required this.caliber,
  });
  final Caliber caliber;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductProvider productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context); //Provider donde se almacenan los objetos Caliber
    return Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: ()=>productProvider.removeCaliberFromProductForm(caliber), //Borra el objeto Caliber de la lis[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
          ),
          const Text("Calibre"),
          TextFormField(
              initialValue: caliber.weight,
              onChanged: (value){
                caliber.weight = value;
              },
          ),
          const Text("Cantidad"),
          TextFormField(
              initialValue: caliber.amount.toString(),
              onChanged: (value){
                try{
                   caliber.amount = int.parse(value);
                } catch(e){
                  print(e);
                }
              },
          ),
          const Text("Precio"),
          TextFormField(
              initialValue: caliber.price.toString(),
              onChanged: (value){
                try{
                  caliber.price = double.parse(value);
                }catch (e){
                  print(e);
                }
              },
          ),
          const Text("Peso por caja"),
          TextFormField(
              initialValue: caliber.weightForBox.toString(),
              onChanged: (value){
                try{
                  caliber.weightForBox = double.parse(value);
                } catch(e){
                  print(e);
                }
              },
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

Así se vería el widget CalibertTextFormFields (*con los estilos gráficos que he omitido*)
[image: CaliberTextFormFields]

La clase `Caliber`, cuyos objetos son editados con el widget anterior:

```
class Caliber {
    Caliber({
        required this.weight,
        required this.price,
        required this.amount,
        required this.weightForBox,
        required this.id,
    });
    int id;
    String weight;
    double price;
    int amount;
    double weightForBox;
}
```

Aquí llamo los `CalibertTextFormFields`:

```
class ProductForm extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ProductProvider productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);
      return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //...
            ..[for (var caliber in productProvider.productForm!.calibers) CaliberTextFormFields(caliber: caliber)],
          ]
}
```

Y el objeto `Product`, dónde se almacenan los objetos de `Caliber` en la propiedad `calibers`. Este objeto `Product` se almacena en el `ProductProvider`:

```
class Product {
    Product({required this.id, required this.name, required this.calibers, required this.media});
    String name;
    String id;
    List<Caliber> calibers; //Aquí se almacenan los objetos de la clase Caliber
    List<String> media; 
    Uint8List? coverImage;
}
```

Finalmente, este es el Provider donde se almacena el `Product` que contiene los `Caliber`:

```
class ProductProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  Product? productForm;

  void addCaliberToProductForm(){  //Agrega un Caliber con ID único a la lista 
        if(productForm!.calibers.isNotEmpty) {
          productForm!.calibers.add(Caliber(
            id:productForm!.calibers.last.id+1, 
            weightForBox:0, 
            weight:"Calibre", 
            price:0, 
            amount:0
          ));
        } else {
          productForm!.calibers.add(Caliber(
            id:0, 
            weightForBox:0, 
            weight:"Calibre", 
            price:0, 
            amount:0
          ));
        }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeCaliberFromProductForm(Caliber caliber){
    productForm!.calibers.removeWhere((element) => element.id == caliber.id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

### Problema

El problema viene en que cuando hay más de dos `Caliber` en la lista y se elimina el de arriba con el `IconButton` de delete, se borra correctamente con la función `removeCaliberFromProductForm`. Pero, al momento de redibujarse el Widget con los `Caliber` restantes el `CaliberTextFormFields` borrado se mantiene mientras que el único que se borra es el último `CaliberTextFormFields` de la lista. De la siguiente forma:

[image: GIF del error]

Sin embargo, utilizando el debugger veo que en la lista del `Product` del `ProductProvider` se borrar el elemento adecuado. Además, al llamar el `CaliberTextFormFields` cuando se redibuja también se pasa el `Caliber` adecuado como parametro, por lo que no se por que se redibujan incorrectamente.

Además, si agrego al principio del `CaliberTextFormFields` un `Text` con los valores del parametro `Caliber` que se le pasan, estos muestran los datos correctos. Por lo que supongo que el prblema debe ser del `TextFormField`.

Lineas agregadas:

```
 Text(caliber.id.toString()),
 Text(caliber.weight),
```

[image: GIF del error]

Convirtiendo `CaliberTextFormFields` en un `Statefulidget` y agregando los siguientes initState y dispose:

```
@override
void initState(){
    print("initState: ${widget.caliber.id.toString()}");
    print("initState: ${widget.caliber.weight}");
    super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose(){
    print("dispose: ${widget.caliber.id.toString()}");
    print("dispose: ${widget.caliber.weight}");
    super.dispose();
}
```

al realizar el procedimiento anterior me pinta lo siguiente:

> I/flutter (13925): dispose: 1
>
> I/flutter (13925): dispose: No debe borrarse

### Posible razón del error

Encontré buscando en la [documentación del TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) lo siguiente que podría ser la razón del error:

> When the widget has focus, it will prevent itself from disposing via
> its underlying EditableText's
> AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.wantKeepAlive in order to avoid losing
> the selection. Removing the focus will allow it to be disposed.

Sin embargo, no se como cambiar esa propiedad.

Comment: dentro de CaliberTextFormFields , usa Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false);  no necesitas escuchar cambios ahí, solo acceder al provider para borrar el elemento

Comment: Lo he cambiado. Pero, el error persiste.

Comment: en que momento instancias `Product(` ?  aquí veo que ya lo tienes instanciado productForm!.calibers.add(Caliber

Comment: El `productForm`, que es el `Product` que se utiliza, se instancia justo antes de abrirse el formulario que contiene el `CaliberTextFormFields`. Si me lo pides agrego el código .Pero, creo que no contiene nada relevante y se aleja un poco del problema en sí. Además, agrego otra información que puede servir que acabo de encontrar.

Comment: una última pregunta, ese valor de "DEBE BORRARSE" y "NO DEBE BORRARSE" tu lo cambias ? o ya los creas así?

Comment: Los cambio yo. Y luego fuerzo un notifylisteners para que actualice los Text que puse para mostrar el ejemplo. Cuando los creo se crean con el valor "Calibre" cómo se ve en el método addCaliberTo...

Comment: podrías hacer esto? convertir class CaliberTextFormFields extends StatelessWidget { a   StatefulWidget,  luego en el State, implementa el initState, ahí pinta estos datos tambien : (caliber.id.toString()),
(caliber.weight),  y muestranos que sale al borrar el elemento

Comment: Ya subí lo que me pediste. El initState no pinta nada, solo lo hace el dispose.

Comment: al momento de pintar el widget/pantalla por primera vez, si pinta el initState no?

Comment: Claro, en ese momento sí. Primero pinta el id y luego la palabra "Calibre", que es lo que corresponde según la función addCaliberToProductForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que puedo entender el error, te lo explico:

```dart
class CaliberTextFormFields extends StatelessWidget {
  const CaliberTextFormFields({
    required this.caliber,
  });
  final Caliber caliber;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductProvider productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context); //Provider donde se almacenan los objetos Caliber
    return Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: ()=>productProvider.removeCaliberFromProductForm(caliber), //Borra el objeto Caliber de la lis[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
          ),
          const Text("Calibre"),
          TextFormField(
              initialValue: caliber.weight,
              onChanged: (value){
                caliber.weight = value;
              },
          ),
```

En esa parte, estás inicializando el `TextFormField` con un valor específico, como el widget no se vuelve a crear, solo el valor se actualiza `caliber.weight` , pero esto ya no afecta al `initialValue` ya que eso solo se crea una vez.

Lo que podrías hacer es cambiarlo a `StatefulWidget` , eliminar esta línea: `initialValue: caliber.weight,` y usar un `TextEditingController`, luego al momento de actualizar el widget, cambiar el valor del textEditingController.

Así:

```dart
// Dentro de tu State

final controller = TextEditingController();

    @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CaliberTextFormFields oldWidget) {
    controller.text = caliber.weight;
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductProvider productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false); //Provider donde se almacenan los objetos Caliber
    return Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: ()=>productProvider.removeCaliberFromProductForm(caliber), //Borra el objeto Caliber de la lis[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
          ),
          const Text("Calibre"),
          TextFormField(
              //initialValue: caliber.weight,
              controller: controller,
              onChanged: (value){
                caliber.weight = value;
              },
          ),
```

Avisas si te funciona :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona correctamente. Entiendo que mi error viene de que yo creía que al redibujarse el padre, también lo hacían los hijos y por ende se volvía a utilizar el initValue. ¿Qué es lo que no es correcto de esto?

Comment: initialValue: caliber.weight, no vuelve a entrar ahí, eso solo la primera vez que se crea, también necesitabas esto: Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false); para que no escuche cambios ahí. Te recomiendo trabajar con TextEditingControllers para manejo de texto en textfields

Comment: ok, muchas gracicas.

Comment: sigueme en youtube :V

Comment: Ya lo hago jaja, hace un par de videos te comente agradeciéndote por ayudarme siempre en SO.